When RoutePattern.RawText may be null?
My controller imports EndpointDataSource to explore available route endpoints in application.
I found that RoutePattern.RawText is nullable string?, and docs say that it "May be null".
The question is when it may be null, since this is valid registered route?
UPD
In other words, are there any valid cases, when RoutePattern.RawText is null for endpoint, which is already registered in application?

A RoutePattern with a null RawText property will be returned from a call to RoutePatternFactory.Patttern(segments: Array.Empty<RoutePatternSegment>(); - though I don't know when or why you'd do this.

Other overloads of static RoutePattern Pattern() in static class RoutePatternFactory also subsequently call into RoutePatternFactory.PatternCore and pass rawText: null - though curiously in my copy of ASP.NET Core 8.0' assemblies the parameter is not marked as nullable - that's probably an oversight.

Probably, I need to clarify the question.

I think it might be null if you have an [AcceptVerbs] attribute without specifying a value for the Template property.
